# View above Dialog?

Tags: java, android

Just a quick question.

Would it be possible to bring a View (Button) above a Dialog that is currently showing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could splash another dialog(that contains a button) ontop of the first one.

If you are aiming to get literally just a button and nothing else you'd have to define a custom layout for a dialog that is all transparent except for your button.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can create it as a custom View on the Dialog, at least (with `AlertDialog.Builder.setView()`

Comment: I agree. You can add the button to the dialog and bind it to the same listener of the other button.